# What was Heawood's proof of maximal planar graph 3-colorable implies its dual is bipartite?

Tags: mathematics

In graph theory, it is a well-known (I guess folklore) result that the following three conditions are equivalent for a maximal planar graph $G$ (definitions are given at the end).

1. Every vertex in $G$ has even degree (in other words, $G$ in
   Eulerian)
2. $G$ is 3-colorable.
3. The dual graph of $G$ is bipartite (ie, 2-colorable)

It is reported that Heawood proved equivalence of (2) and (3) in "On the four-color map problem" (Quart. J. Pure Math, 1898). It seems to me that this paper is not available (at least not online). Ore's book [The four-color problem](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-four-color-problem/ore/978-0-12-374571-2) gave a simple proof of (2) implies (3) (see Theorem 7.4.3, it is on page 100). **I would like to know who came up with this proof first.** I think Heawood was aware of this simple proof. Or **was his proof of (2) implies (3) different?** If so, what was (the basic idea of) his proof?

*Definitions:*
A (simple) graph $G$ is said to be *maximal planar* (or triangulated) if $G$ has a plane drawing without edge crossings such that every face boundary is a triangle (adding one more edge would make the graph non-planar; hence the name maximal planar). A *coloring* of a graph $G$ is a function $f$ on the vertex set of $G$ such that endpoints of each edge get different 'colours' (ie, $f(u)\neq f(v)$ for every edge $\{u,v\}$ of $G$). For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, a $k$-coloring is a coloring that uses at most $k$ colors.

Comment: [Heawood's paper](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b417549&view=1up&seq=282) (Quart. J. Pure Math., 29 (1898), 270-285) is available for free viewing on HathiTrust website.

Comment: @Conifold, Thank you for pointing out this. But, it is behind a copyright wall.

Comment: It should be accessible at most university libraries or by interlibrary loan.